# RDBMS, foreign key merged or separate table?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have an `ai_order` table.

```
CREATE TABLE `ai_order`(
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `product_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `quantity` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `number` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `addDate` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `orderProduct`(`product_id`,`number`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

As an order from a client contains many product with quantity which means multiple rows being inserted for a single order, for example an order contains a 50 product being resulted in creation of 50 rows in `ai_order` table. now to to identify an individual order i have given a number field which will hold the unique order number (serial) for a single order i.e it will group `order_id` by `number` field. below is the table demonstrating how the data is going to be stored in the table.

[image: ai_order]

There will be many tables which will be extending from this parent table. while everything is correct the problem i see is `number` column repeating the value again and again, considering i have `200` product to be listed the for one order i will have to repeat the `number` column value again and again in all `200` rows which gives me somewhat ugly feeling.

Now the method to solve this crisis is by storing the order `number` in a different table.(although repetition cannot be avoided, but not a problem). for example how about removing the `number` column from the `ai_order` table and storing it this way.

```
CREATE TABLE `ai_order_number`(
    `order_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `number` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

i would like your take on how to deal with this approach? which one would you go with. the first or the later one? any suggestions on improvement will be appreciated.

thank you.

Comment: I would stick to your first option. That seems correctly normalized to me, and you have to maitain a second table in the other example, which seems like over kill.

Comment: Just another question, is the number field a foreign key to another orders table? That is the way I would implement it, and that the table ai_order is merely a many to many table between products and orders.

Comment: number is the reference number to be given to client, further extended it is used to group rows altogether, `ai_order` is the parent table which consist of two child tables `ai_order_invoice` which holds the quotation of pricing details, and `ai_order_packing` which holds the information related to shipment and packing to be sent via cargo.

Comment: customer --> order --> line item; see this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520289/multiple-column-foreign-key-contraints/4522171#4522171

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it will be a good idea to keep a separate table as you suggested as order_number is directly related to order.

If you are still planning to keep a different table, take '`add_date`' along with number. I'm finding '`add_date`' more uglier than order number.

In case exact timing of adding order is not useful, which is generally the case, you can keep a separate table which will have `customer_id`, `order_number`(primary key), `order_date`

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the first approach since there's nothing wrong with repeating the order number in that table and therefore there's no need to create a second table that will have the order number repeated anyway.

What I would do instead, is perhaps getting rid off the `id` column and make `number` the primary key of the table since you are more likely to perform searches, joins, etc, by the order number than by the `id` column. The `number` column could be automatically generated as well so that won't be an issue.

Comment: The number column seems to be a foreign key to the orders table, so your plan seems flawed. You will not be able to make it the soul primary key, you will have to use something like (number,product_id) or even (number,product_id, addDate) if the OP allows the user to add the same product twice to an order

Comment: @astander nope, only a single product is allowed for one order. @Icarus what you are suggesting is logically incorrect to do so. as i have many other tables which will relate to this parent table i need an `id` column to identify each rows that belong to a single order and number field to group all together.

Comment: Productid,number are already unique. Look at the table definition. However, your point is valid; I just read the question again and id is clearly fk. My point is that id seems unnecessary: He defined ordernumber as varchar yet it appears to store only numbers and is a sequential number or so it appears. Order number should be enough to link all tables w/o using this extra id column that doesn't seem to serve a very useful purpose.

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar yes, I agree, you cannot remove the id column at this stage, but its not clear to me the usefulness of this column from the beginning, I mean, order number should have been enough to link all tables; besides, it appears as if only integers are stored, therefore, why define it as varchar?

Comment: storing of integer was just an example.number consist of hyphen(-), chars and ints, this is why varchar. the structure of application is such that first an order is received from the client and the records are maintained in order table, which does not include any pricing details. after the order is received there are two stages for quoting the price, first is quotation (initial invoice) and then final invoice. now i have to quote price for each and every order_id, therefore i need `id` column, and i need to generate a unique number for reference to be given to client and that is why number.

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar I understand. In that case, id column is needed but my initial recommendation of going with the first approach still holds: there's no need to create a second table, you gain nothing by doing that and there's nothing wrong with repeating the order number in the first approach.