# Normalization and Relationships

Tags: database, database-design

I have master entity MasterA that has a detail entity DetailB. I have a separate entity DetailC that has a foreign key to DetailB.

In my queries I query a lot the DetailC list but I must query DetailC in relation to MasterA. In this case does it make sense to make a foreign key relationship between DetailC and MasterA to speed up querying. (rather than doing a join with DetailB). At the application layer, 
 I would make sure that the FK in DetailC is in sync (with what is specified at DetailB).
Thanks!

Comment: I think that the pertinent question is - why is the foreign key in DetailB in the first place? To use an example from my work, a delivery note from a supplier (MasterA) contains lines (DetailB) about the parts delivered. Each part has several lines of specifications (DetailC). I could query the database asking which specification came from which order (ie DetailC and MasterA), but the data *has* to go through DetailB. A direct link between MasterA and DetailC is meaningless.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think there are some cases where the relation could make sense. If we extend your example so that for every delivery note line, you have a purchase order line. It could make sense to get all purchase order lines in relation to the master delivery note (wihtout having to go through the supplier.

Comment: The reason that the purchase order line is connected to the delivery note line is that a delivery note can contain lines from different orders. If the delivery note were connected directly to the order, then a note could only be created for one order.

Comment: Propagate keys, like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520289/multiple-column-foreign-key-contraints/4522171#4522171

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a field to DetailC which would be a foreign key with respect to MasterA. But if DetailC has a relation with DetailB and DetailB has a relation with MasterA, then this extra field would be redundant. Strict normalisation would say that there should not be such a field, but you should be able to relax the normalisation rules as long as you can guarantee that there will be no discrepancies in the data.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depending on what about your data.

If in your opinion you think DetailC and MasterA have something related, i think make sense to do that.

Or if you worry about efficiency, i think in design trade-off is always happen. In this case you have to increase your data size to trade with your speed (or your convenient).