# Database relation of purchased items

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, database-design

I'm trying to come up with a database relation to keep track of purchased items that will be used for look up afterwards--for example ebooks. Ignore the ellipses--they represent miscellaneous data such as timestamp, etc...

Here's the table I have right now:

```
purchased:
transaction_id(int)(pk)(auto_inc) | username (varchar) | purchases (text) | ...
```

In this design, the column "purchases" is just a string of text that would contain the item_id of items purchased, separated by commas. Simplified example: "book1, book23, book5, book8".

In a successful transaction, this query would insert the transaction data into the "purchased" table:

```
INSERT INTO purchased VALUES (null, username, purchases, ...)
```

---

From this point on, two things can happen:

1. The user can lookup what ebooks they've purchased
2. The user can make another purchase transaction.

If the user (theusername) wants to see their ebooks, the system performs a selection query e.g.

```
SELECT purchases FROM purchased WHERE username=theusername
```

which returns a string containing the item IDs.

One a sidenot, is it possible to get an php array of purchases without having to use extra php code, i.e. explode? **Can you use something besides the data type "text" in SQL to store a list of items?** If not, that's okay.

---

Either way, here's the main problem. Say the user makes another transaction--there will now be two rows in "purchased" that contains the user's purchased items. That means that in this table, the user's purchases are split into multiple rows.

Ideally, I want these purchases to all be in the same row. I can't use an UPDATE statement because each purchase has it's own unique transaction_id.

I was thinking that I could make another table that contains all purchases by a user

```
all_purchased:
username (pk) | purchases (text) | ...
```

and whenever the user makes another transaction, the "all_purchased" table would just update its purchases column with the item ID of any new ebooks.

But this table seems redundant because the selection query I mentioned would get the task done.

**What would be the best way to structure the database relation(s)?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that you are using relational database -- in there any special reason not to use normalized tables?  Here is just one possibility.

[image]

This one propagates keys; if you have an ORM of some kind that has trouble with composite keys, modify **[as in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520289/multiple-column-foreign-key-contraints/4522171#4522171)**.

Comment: Thank you for the diagram. It clearly illustrates how propagating foreign keys can remove data redundancy.

Answer (score 1):

I think its not a good idea to maintain the purchased book_ids in same row as comma separated values. **Better to define a new table as :**

```
  purchased_books:
      transaction_book_id(int)(pk)(auto_inc) | transaction_id(int) | book_id(int)
```

Also define foreign key relationships of transaction_id and book_id column with their respective tables i.e. `purchased` and `books`.

Hopefully, rest of your problems will be solved by using this new table.

Comment: I see. What would be the main benefit of using another table to maintain the purchased books rather than keep the books as a string separated by commas? If a user bought 10 books, for example, wouldn't it be more optimal to insert just one row using the previous relation than to insert 10 extra rows by using a new table?

Comment: @Yau: I am not sure why you think that keeping comma separated values is more optimal. May be you are counting rows and tables. If so, that is not something optimal. By doing so, you make you data  organization,   data retrieval and manipulation etc very complex. Take an example, if one book is returned and you want to delete from the list or you want to retrieve one particular book or you want to count which book is bought by how many buyers, all these queries are going to be complex if not impossible. DB systems are there to  make your data organization simple and maintainable.